# SQL Join vs Sub-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running MySQL 5.1.71.  In my database there are three tables - load, brass and mfg with load being my "main" table.  My goal is to query load and have mfg.name included in the results.  I've tried various iterations of `JOIN` clauses vs sub-queries both with and without `WHERE` clauses.  It seems this should be pretty trivial so I'm not sure how I can't arrive at the solution.

```
load
-------------------------
| id | desc  | brass_id |
-------------------------
|  1 | One   |        2 |
|  2 | Two   |        1 |
-------------------------

brass
---------------
| id | mfg_id |
---------------
|  1 |      6 |
|  2 |      8 |
---------------

brass_mfg
------------------------
| id | name            |
------------------------
|  6 | This Company    |
|  8 | That Company    |
------------------------
```

My desired results would be...

```
results
---------------------------
| load  | mfg             |
---------------------------
| One   | That Company    |
| Two   | This Company    |
---------------------------
```

- A load ID will always have only a single brass ID
- A brass ID will always have only a single mfg ID

**EDIT**
**The previously provided sample data (above) has been updated.  Also, below are the query I'm running and the results I'm getting.  The company is wrong in each record that is returned.  I've included in the query and the results the IDs across the tables.  The company names that appear are not the names in for the IDs in the mfg table.**

```
SELECT 
    load.id AS "load.id", 
    load.brass_id AS "load.brass_id", 
    brass.id AS "brass.id", 
    brass.mfg_id AS "brass.mfg_id", 
    brass_mfg.id AS "brass_mfg.id", 
    brass_mfg.name AS "brass_mfg.name" 
FROM `load`
LEFT JOIN brass ON load.brass_id = brass.id
LEFT JOIN brass_mfg ON brass.id = brass_mfg.id 


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| load.id | load.brass_id | brass.id | brass.mfg_id | brass_mfg.id | brass_mfg.name     |   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 2             | 2        | 6            | 2            | Wrong Company      |
| 2       | 1             | 1        | 8            | 1            | Incorrect Company  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Joins are the basic building blocks of SQL queries.  They should be your first option.  To optimise, then look at indexes.

Comment: I really don't see the problem here.

Comment: Worth mentioning is that your desired result looks like you assume that each `product` will have one `mfg` but association table - `lot` - is usually used in many-to-many relations... Be aware of that!

Comment: @Darek - yes, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your tables and see what data relates to one another then build up joins table by table to get your desired output.

```
SELECT p.desc AS Product, m.name AS mfg
FROM product p
INNER JOIN lot l ON p.lot_id = l.id
INNER JOIN mfg m ON l.mfg_id = m.id
```

Comment: The problem was a combination of the right join type and having the correct left and right tables.  In particular your last join is what set me straight.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your join query.
Try this one:

```
Select 
 l.id AS "load.id", 
 l.brass_id AS "load.brass_id", 
 b.id AS "brass.id", 
 b.mfg_id AS "brass.mfg_id",
 m.id AS "brass_mfg.id",
 m.`name` AS "brass_mfg.name"
FROM `load` as l
LEFT JOIN brass as b ON l.brass_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN brass_mfg as m ON b.mfg_id = m.id
```

[image]

You need `LEFT JOIN` only

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is the closest I have come but I am getting bad results.  Putting together additional info to edit into the original post.

Comment: I think `LEFT JOIN` is the best approach for your design, If you have some bad results you may put them so we can help you.

Comment: Updated original post to reflect more real data, added query and results.

Answer (score 0):

If this is single - single relationship, why having middle table?
In your case the best scenario is simple join.

```
SELECT pt.desc as Product, mfg.name as Mfs
FROM Product pt
Join Lot lt on lt.id = pt.lot_id
Join Mfg mf on mf.id = lt.mfg_id
```

Comment: A given product will only have a single lot and, thus, a single mfg.  However, there can be multiple products pointing to the same lot.  Additionally, there are various fields in each table that necessitate having the tables split up such as they are.